# org.apache.jasper.JasperException, I am noob, don't know what to do

Tags: html, jsp-tags, struts-1, tomcat9

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [/hello.jsp] at line [3]

```
1: <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="h" %>
2: 
3: <h:form action="/hello">
4:     <h:text property="name"/>
5:     <h:submit/>
6:
```

Comment: What's the entire exception from the log? Are there any startup exceptions/warnings in the logs? What's the *actual* version of Struts being used?

Answer (score 0):

You should close the `<h:form>` with `</h:form>`.

Comment: <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="h" %>
<h:form action="/hello">
    <h:text property="name"/>
    <h:submit/>
    <hr />
    <h:errors/>
</h:form>  It is not working, again the same error

Comment: Then we need more of your Project Setup, e.g. pom.xml